# Export Data from AWS S3 bucket to MySql RDS instance using JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to import CSVs in my s3 bucket into my MySql rds instance using jdbc. It is a one time process and not an ongoing one. Interested in knowing the end to end process.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned its one time activity, hence I would like you to suggest direct CSV import to MySQL rather then using JDBC unless there is specific reason you might have that you have not mentioned into the question.

Here is approach you could utilize,

```
for loop of your files in S3, the use following command to import data to MySQL RDS.
>mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

Please refer following for more details.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html

I hope this provides you way to move forward. If I'm missing something, re-frame your question, I could reattempt the answer.